# address already in use :::8080 but port isn't being used by any process

Tags: node.js

I ran this code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1290:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1338:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1425:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dell/foo.js:6:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1317:8)
    at internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:763:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:303:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:872:3)
```

So, here is some code I invoked in order to find out the process running at the port in the terminal:

```
❯  fuser  8080/tcp

~
```

But it turns out there is no process running on that port.

How do I fix this?

(I am new to node.js. I will appreciate any help in the right direction.)

Comment: It's worth checking with `lsof` to see if it's something `fuser` can't find, or if this is some kind of SELinux thing.

Comment: Just reboot your machine.